# 50s-60s short story, Astronauts being attacked on an alien planet by an invisible alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I can't remember the name of a short story that was in an anthology book of vintage SciFi that I read about 30 years ago. The stories were from the 40s-60s I believe.

It was about a spaceship crew being attacked by an alien which could teleport and would only be visible for an instant as it moved from location to location across the landscape in a series of "jumps". After killing most of the crew they finally figured out the jump pattern the alien was using and killed it at one of its jump points.

Any help with the title or author?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice question; do you have any recollection of what the cover art of the anthology might have been?

Comment: Sorry, no. I looked online for Anthologies (hardback) to see if I recognized the book, but no luck. It was some like Golden Age of SciFi by famous authors. Been too long....

Comment: Sounds like something A.E. van Vogt would have written.

Answer (score 1):

"[The Last Bounce](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45597)" by William Tenn is a story about space explorers on a strange planet where four-dimensional creatures roam.  Since these creatures exist in four dimensions they can disappear and reappear at will.  The creatures kill two out of the three explorers but one escapes (though doesn't kill the creature)